# Hide empty divs

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I have a WordPress footer file that display 3 social network icons as `<li>` based on inputs in the themes options panel.

All works fine if there is 1 or more link/image but if there are none, in the rendered source code I am left with open/closing `<div>` and `<li>` with no data in them. As far as visitors are concerned they would be none the wiser, but is there a way to hide these tags if there is no data.

This is the code I am using;

```
<div class="eight columns">
 <div class="social">
  <ul>
  <?php
  foreach (array("twitter","facebook","linkedin") as $option)
      ($tmp=of_get_option('fab_social_'.$option.'_url')) && (print('<li><a href="'.$tmp.'"><img src="'.of_get_option('fab_social_'.$option.'_icon').'" alt="Follow us on '.ucfirst($option).'"></a></li>'));
  ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you already the answer to that on your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381219/make-multiple-php-if-statements-more-efficient see the last answer it shows how you check if an item is empty, from there make a check.

Comment: @Prix, that is a different question/answer. This is about how to hide tags altogether when there is no information to display.

Comment: Naz if you had the minimal understanding of the problem you've posted then yes the above link should answer your own question. As you can see on the last answer there he uses `if (!emtpy($social1))` to verify if a social option is present what happens if u do that before the div for all the social networks ? `if (!empty($social1) && !empty($social2) && !empty($social3)) {` ? **but don't worry there is always some one to spoonfed those who don't like to learn.**

Comment: @Prix so funny, chillout. If you have looked at the original question in the link you provided you must know that I already know enough to write basic conditional statements, and you must therefore be able to deduce that I must be able to write a simple AND statement. But that's not what I am after. On top of that if I am unwilling to learn why was I in the original link trying to make my own work more efficient?

Comment: Then you're starting with the wrong thing, first that function is not fit for what you want, you should create your own custom social media function, second, the table structure used for options is not fit for what you're doing and won't yield any performance for u, you should also make your own social table which is easy enough, third, having 2 foreach's is not any more efficient than pre-saving the variables since you need to query each of it in order to retrieve every single data. **"Do you just think it is inefficient, or do you have evidence that it's inefficient?"**

Comment: @Prix, I don't understand anything you have written. Can you expand a little. TBH right now I was only hoping for some JS or something that would simply hide empty tags

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd setup the options first, then evaluate to see whether or not to display.

```
<?php
// Get all stored options
$socials = array();
foreach ( array( 'twitter', 'facebook', 'linkedin' ) as $option ){
    $setting = of_get_option('fab_social_'.$option.'_url');
    if ( $setting != '' ) $socials[ $option ] = $setting;
}


?>
<div class="eight columns">
<?php if ( count( $socials ) > 0 ) { /* check are any social options set, don't display unless >0 */ ?>
<div class="social">
<ul>
<?php
// Loop through options
foreach ( $socials as $option=>$setting ){
    print('<li><a href="'.$setting.'"><img src="'.of_get_option('fab_social_'.$option.'_icon').'" alt="Follow us on '.ucfirst($option).'"></a></li>'));
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php } /* Close initial count() comparison */ ?>
</div>
```